# Shaping negative pulses to positive ones pt2

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pulse, inverting-amplifier

I asked a questing a few weeks ago, and asked a follow up question as a answer to that post? Apparently that's not allowed, so I am making this post instead.

The question is based on this thread:
[Shaping negative pulses to positive ones](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365566/shaping-negative-pulses-to-positive-ones?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Question: 
The op amp that I chose has sufficient properties. However, I can't get my schematic to work. See the picture below for my schematic.

The output I am getting is my Vcc+, which is odd. I am not getting the pulses that I was looking for. I think I did something wrong, does anybody have any ideas?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What type of opamp have you been using?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2081a.pdf TLE2081

Comment: Read here https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/archive/2012/05/08/op-amp-voltage-ranges-input-and-output-clearing-some-confusion and check if you opamp meet the common-mode input voltage range in your circuit.

Comment: Probe the (+) input with your scope.  Do you have 0V at that point?  Ground your input to the 10k resistor, what do you measure at the opamp output?

Comment: Your sketch shows a negative going pulse at the input, but only a relative amplitude.  To be certain, please identify your zero baseline.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.